# Sequence of measurable which is a "$k$-partition" the space

Tags: measure-theory

Let  $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measurable space with $0<\mu(X)<\infty$
Let $(A_n)$be a sequence of measurable sets and $k>0$ a natural number, and suppose that every $x \in X$ is conteined in at most $k$ sets of the sequence.

Prove:

(i) $\sum_n \mu(A_n) \leq k\mu(X)$
(ii) if every $x$ is contained in infinite elements of the sequence, then $\sum_n \mu(A_n)= \infty$

What i tried by far:
That seems easy to see, but cant find a good way to prove.
$B_j$:= {x | x is contained j times in (A_n) } and my goal was proving 
$\sum_{j=1}^k \mu(B_j )j  \ge \sum_n \mu(A_n)$
But I dont think those $B_j$ are measurable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $1_{A_n}$ denotes the indicator function of $A_n$. Then we have
$$ \sum_n \mu (A_n) = \sum_n \int 1_{A_n} =  \int \underbrace{\sum_n 1_{A_n}}_{\le k} \le k \mu(X). $$

You are allowed to switch the (infinite) sum with the integral, as each $1_{A_n}$ is non-negative. If you want to be pedantic, go for the partial sums.

You can adapt this idea also for the second part of the question. Just estimate the interval from below.